# Call R from java - different R version

Tags: java, r, version, environment-variables

On the computers (running fedora) at my work R-2.15 is installed by default. I downloaded R-3.0.2 because I need several packages which are only available for R 3.

When i try to call an Rscript from java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` with command being the String Array `{"/path/to/Rscript/3-0" "name/of/script" "...args..."}` I get the error `WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME` and it says that it couldn't load the needed packages. When i run the very same command in a terminal it works well.

What is the difference between the call via java and the call on the console. And how can I fix it?

EDIT 1:
when i run my locally installed R-3 version, `libPaths` returns

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/<homedir>/.bin/R-3.0.2/library"
```

But when i call an Rscript from Java, `libPaths` returns

```
[1] "/home/<homedir>/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                                          
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"                                          
[4] "/home/<homedir>/.bin/R-3.0.2/library"
```

The problem seems to be that Java adds any environment variables that tell `R` to load packages from the 2.15 installation. How can i prevent this?

EDIT 2:
When i list all environment variables using the `System.getenv();` method nothing `R`-related is shown, the same is the case when i list the environment variables using `printenv` in the terminal. But when i call `Sys.getenv` in R the variables R_HOME, R_LIBS, ... are defined. How are these defined?

Comment: This will be much easier to diagnose if you provide a reproducible example.  What is the value of `R_HOME`?  What does your script contain?  Where are the libraries in each case (what does `.libPaths()` return)?  Are you sure that you are using the same version of R in both cases (what does `version` return)?

Comment: I added information about the libPaths. You are right, that seems to be the problem.... But how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the library to look in when you load the package.  For example, when calling the script via Rscript, you could use

```
library(rJava, lib.loc = .libPaths()[4])
```

Comment: Yes, i know but i want to write a java application and such a workaround will only work on my computer but not in general... `libPaths()` should be something like `c("<default of the installation>", "<home-of-user>/R/<arch>/<R-version>")`

Comment: Maybe use `.Library` or `.Library.site`, both described in the `?.libPaths` help page.  You probably may to let the users decide where they are installing and loading their packages though.  A better solution would be to work out when and where those extra libraries are being set.  You'll have to do some digging.